# git command line unable to commit and the message is below

Tags: git

```
$ git push origin master
```

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Comment: What does `git remote -v` show?

Answer (score 1):

If you've created a repo, copy the link and type `git remote add origin` and paste repo's link

Answer (score 0):

This message sometimes comes up of you fail to connect to the remote repo, for example if the authentication failed.